# Jquery disabled select tag in a form

Tags: jquery

I have a form.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <select id="packageId">
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="duration">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

1. I want the Select tag with ID duration set disabled = true at first.
2. When user make a change on Select tag with ID packageId AND the value is 1, remove the disabled on Select Tag with ID duration.
3. When user make another change on Select tag with ID packageId AND the value is back to zero, make Selec Tag with ID duration have disabled.

Here is my jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change','#packageId', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '0') {
      $("#duration").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#duration").attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

This Jquery cannot set disabled = true at first. I have to click on Option 1, and back to Option 0 to make it desabled. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: you should use .prop()

Comment: whether the element is created dynamically

Comment: It create dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For initially setting the disabled state you need to trigger the change event once the change handler is added.

If the select element is not added dynamically, there is no need to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#packageId').on('change', function () {
        $("#duration").prop('disabled', $(this).val() != '1');
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvseoq8j/)

---

If the element is added dynamically, then you need to fire the change event once the select element is added

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#packageId', function () {
        $("#duration").prop('disabled', $(this).val() != '1');
    })
    //then once the select elements are added trigger the event
    $('#packageId').trigger('change');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pvseoq8j/3/)

Comment: Hmm, weird, in your fiddle it works as i want, but in my code its not. In my code, it disabled as initial, that part is correct, But no matter how i change the Select tag with packageId ID, it still DISABLED.

Comment: Ah, i think your way crashed with Bootstrap Select. In the select tag, i remove "class='selectpicker'" It works perfectly, when i put it back on, the problem occur. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#packageId', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '0') {
      $("#duration").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#duration").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <select id="packageId">
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select id="duration">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```